# How to explain a short-term job to a potential employer?

Tags: software-industry, job-change, new-hires

I read [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23791/how-do-you-explain-previous-short-term-positions-to-potential-future-employers), [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7255/quitting-job-on-short-term-notice) and [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42797/would-a-short-term-job-in-different-industry-permanently-harm-my-web-dev-career) post, however my situation is little different than all of these. Mine is a preemptive question.

I am working as a data analyst. I'm expecting a lay-off at my current company due to cut backs in my department. I have been working here for about 2.5 years. As of now, I have accepted another job, however, I already am aware that it will involve manual work, will give me little opportunity to learn new technologies and I will be under-paid (slightly below average). I am on a work-visa so the day I become unemployed, I have to leave the country. Because of this, I cannot wait to find out if I've been affected in the lay-off. So I was forced to accept this position because nothing else materialized. I didn't apply for this position - it sort of fell in my lap. I'm not being provided any relocation or sign-on bonus so I do not have to refund the employer if I leave.

While I am aware that I can always ask for a better project/opportunity once I join, I don't expect good work to come my way because I know the stage of project they are in - there is no interesting work. Sticking it out might mean nothing for me because this is a 12-month contract.

As I already mentioned, this job will be a step-down and I will continue my job-search. I am aware that if I change my mind anytime between signing the offer letter till only a few weeks into the new job, I burn that bridge. I am willing to take that risk for a considerably better opportunity.

The positive aspect of this job besides the employment is that it will give me a chance to relocate to an area where there are many more options for my skills.

I do not want to omit this (potentially) short-term employment. Such omissions usually turn out badly during immigration processes. That is something I absolutely cannot risk. My question is how do I explain to a potential employer why I'm looking to move out immediately after joining without coming off as flaky and without bad-mouthing my employer?

Comment: The thing with visa issues is that the hiring managers aren't aware of the complexity involved. And mentioning things about visa only scares most employers away. I treat this like a salary conversation - postpone the until they have given an offer letter. At this point, most likely an immigration specialist usually gets involved, but not before.

Answer (score 3):

Companies hiring employees with work visas probably understand how important it is for you to maintain employment of any kind in their company.

I don't think you have a lot to worry about when looking for other jobs. Be upfront that you are leaving because you prefer the job they're offering over the one you have. It's a pretty good reason to leave a job. If you're asked why you took this job in the first place, your explanation in this post is pretty valid in my opinion. It's not like you're making the rules of work visas and staying in a foreign land (hate the game and not the player).

Your bigger problem will be disappointing your current employer. It's possible they recognize this isn't your ideal situation, but they hired you to get someone qualified even if that means getting someone over-qualified. Try to give ample notice. Explain that you understand they're not in a position to offer the kind of work you really want, so you don't hold that against them. The impact this will have on them is probably proportional to how honest you were during the hiring process.  Maybe they didn't ask enough or the right questions. That's not your fault.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I will give at least the two week notice and try my best not to burn the bridge there because while the project is small, the employer is a big company.