# How to answer short employment stay on CV

Tags: interviewing, communication, united-kingdom

My CV has been filled with short employments lately, I have to confess my shortcoming that I don't know what to look for in the company when researching the role/company and how to judge if it is good or not, sometimes it wasn't a great fit.

The last company I worked for hired me way less than what I was earning before where I was let go because of redundancy.

I was working in my last job where conditions weren't ideal (not much work, much monitoring fewer hands-on(I am a developer)), plus way too little salary. The problem started when I asked for raise as the recruiter who recruited me said that they would 'Match the salary' after probation which never happened because it wasn't written so I had to decide and I left that company.

A potential employer has asked me why I asked last 3 short roles, I have answer to the one before i.e. redundancy and contracted ended.

How do I phrase why I left the last role? Talking about my financial problem or I was hired way less will raise a red flag. How can I answer a short-term role on my CV that is in my favor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain a short-term job to a potential employer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/76266/how-to-explain-a-short-term-job-to-a-potential-employer)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere As much as I like to say no, unfortunately I did and over a year passed and still out of work

Comment: @localhost Can you maybe add a rough timeline in your post? Bullet points like "JobA (June 2020 - August 2020) Let go due to redundancies." would help clear up your timeline considerably. (Also, was there any long-term employment or education before this string of small jobs?)

Comment: @localhost, a year to be out of work completely is a long time. I'd suggest that *not having work* is the main problem to be explained, not just that the previous roles were short-term. That said, being made redundant from one job, taking a short-term contract role to tide you over, and then finally ending up with something that "didn't quite fit", shouldn't require much explanation. Just avoid badmouthing the previous employer - you won't normally be invited to denounce former employers, and nothing good will come of doing so on your own initiative. Hirers know bad employers exist.

Answer (score 1):

[6 months ago](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/173619/how-to-tell-my-manager-i-have-lost-interest-in-job-due-to-i-t-problem) you were employed. You left that employment to go do a bootcamp course  and you started looking for work again [in August '21](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/177668/how-to-know-what-salary-should-i-be-on).

So with that in mind..

> How do I phrase why I left the last role?

You left to pursue a course because you believed that would help you upskill.

> Talking about my financial problem or I was hired way less will raise a red flag.

Yeah don't talk about those.

> How can I answer a short-term role on my CV that is in my favor?

As above, the **truth**. Not because it will be in your favor (it won't be) but because it will be the *least* damaging.

Comment: The reason I didn't mention my CV is because It will look like a job hopper or mentally disturbed person who isn't serious about doing a job so I left that out

Comment: @localhost are you able to clear up the confusion?

Answer (score -4):

#### Just tell them why

None of the reasons you gave above are problematic.  Just tell them the truth.  Leave out your personal circumstances.

1. Laid off/made redundant
2. Did not get promised pay increase
3. whatever

Comment: @JoeStrazzere "have been out of work for over a year" is based on facts not currently in evidence.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere ,answers are to the question, not to comments

Answer (score -4):

### Spin it as short term projects

First of all, make a final and rational decision : **do you want to be developer or not** . Times are tough, you don't have much experience and probably lack skill. Therefore, it **is unlikely you will find perfect job**. It is more likely you will find junior position where you will be given "boring" tasks and little freedom. Plus, the pay won't be great. Your goal would be to survive, gain some experience&skill and hopefully find better position while still employed.

Now, how could you spin your prior working experience ? To avoid being labeled as job hopper (unreliable) or someone laid of as redundant (incompetent), try to spin your employment history as temporary jobs. You were working on a project, project has been completed and that is that. Of course, do not use this for all of your latest jobs. One loss of job could be explained by COVID-19 and related economic crisis. If they ask why didn't you look for more permanent position, say you were studying , traveling the world etc ...

One thing to remember is **do not omit shorter job histories**. Instead, be proud about them, spin it as a successful project in interesting technology. Remember, those interviewing you do not know you were bored, underpaid and underutilized. If you try to gloss over it they will "sense" the truth. But if you are a bit boastful about them, they could partially believe you.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, it would not be because no one could know what are you hired for, and background check would not reveal. "Yes, OP worked from us from xx-xx-xxxx to yy-yy-yyyy as a developer" , and that is that. Especially in at will employment states you could hire someone for few weeks if you both agree to that. You do not need to have temporary contract.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Due to various privacy laws background checks are now limited to duration and position. As for lies : welcome to the real world :) Companies lie to employees/candidates and employees/candidates lie to companies.